# find and select a file in the phone memory

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application and I would like to select a file in my phone. Do you have ideas to do it?

I would like that when I click on the icon it opens to me the files of the phone
(I do not necessarily want the code to be finished, but just creser tracks)
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Comment: Try Intent Chooser, this will open an default file manager, and you will be able to search files for use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start an intent to get the files with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

and receive the picked file with:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
    case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
            ...
        }
        break;
    }
}
```